# Como puedo renderizar contenido matemático a PDF en React (react-katex, @react-pdf/renderer)

Tags: reactjs, pdf, latex

Quiero hacer que el usuario en mi sitio de ensayos de matemáticas, pueda descargar los ejercicios en formato PDF, pero no logro que se renderice adecuadamente, también probé con la librería látex. El siguiente es solo un ejemplo para no ensuciar  el código principal.

```js
const MyDocument = () => (
  <Document>
    <Page style={styles.page}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>Ejemplo de PDF con ecuaciones</Text>
      <Text style={styles.equation}>
        Una ecuación en línea: <InlineMath math="E = mc^2" />
      </Text>
      <Text style={styles.equation}>
        Otra ecuación en línea: <InlineMath math="\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} dx = \sqrt{\pi}" />
      </Text>
    </Page>
  </Document>
);
```